# Client data manager app with sharing permission settings for iOS AND Android

Tags: android, ios, client

As an Infrastructure professional I am looking for an app where I can store client data information like password, login, etc, that be **searchble** (like "Server Password", and all the clients Server passwords will be displayed), that be **scaleble** (no client or item limit), that be **shareble** (so a new employee that just arrived can have specific informations that I share with him and that I can revoke when he leave the company), that be tagged and organized in a way easy way to find.

Once I can't find this on internet and have no skills (right now) to devolep iOS and Android app to do this, I am thinking to give a try to Google Sheets and try to adapt the screen to smartphones.

I even heard that you can convert google sheets to apps with a certain program.

Any help me is most welcome.